# Ember Data list of Strings/Numbers

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

how to declare model in Ember data that has list of parametrs (strings, numbers)?

Ember data provides only 3 methods: `DS.attr, DS.hasMany, DS.belongsTo`. I could declare it as custom Parameter Model that has single parameter name. But this seems redundant. DS.hasMany('string') is not working, exception is thrown that there is no model declared 'String'.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DS.hasMany` and `DS.belongsTo` are for relationships, not attributes. You need to use `DS.attr`, but you need to define a `Transform` first. You can see how to do that [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Transform.html).

Comment: Can you expand upon your answer? The documentation you linked to is presently a bit rough; the example and sample usage are for two different transforms. Even then, it's not clear how I can use this to get back an array of strings or numbers without creating a new model. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks. I swear I tried something like that before, but this got it fixed.